# SQL Server 2012 : Between issue with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, between

I am having an issue with the query below:

```
SELECT 
   tT.RequestID, 
   TStatus, 
   TLead, 
   RequestDate, 
   tG.Category, 
   tETM.RAgency, 
   ECost, 
   tTT.TType 
FROM 
    tT AS tT 
INNER JOIN 
    tTMain AS tETM ON tT.RequestID = tETM.RequestID 
INNER JOIN 
    tTType AS tTT ON tETM.AMod = tTT.TypeID 
INNER JOIN 
    tGup AS tG ON tT.Category = tG.CategoryID 
WHERE 
    tT.active = 1 
    AND (ApproxDate BETWEEN '09/30/2016' AND '09/30/2017') 
    AND tT.Category = 3
```

I am currently getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The way I populate the above query in code:

```
string theQ = "SELECT " +
    "tT.RequestID, " +
    "TStatus, " +
    "TLead, " +
    "RequestDate, " +
    "tG.Category, " +
    "tETM.RAgency, " +
    "ECost, " +
    "tTT.TType " +
"FROM " +
    "tT AS tT " +
"INNER JOIN " +
    "tTMain AS tETM " +
"ON " +
    "tT.RequestID = tETM.RequestID " +
"INNER JOIN " +
    "tTType AS tTT " +
"ON " +
    "tETM.AMod = tTT.TypeID " +
"INNER JOIN " +
    "tGup AS tG " +
"ON " +
    "tT.Category = tG.CategoryID " +
"WHERE " +
    "tT.active = @val1 " +
"AND " +
    "(ApproxDate BETWEEN @val2 AND @val3) " +
"AND " +
    "tT.Category = @val4"

//Split up the between check. (it looks like this: BETWEEN 'xx/xx/xxxx' AND 'xx/xx/xxxx')
string[] betweenSplit = Regex.Split(Session["between"].ToString(), " AND ");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet _ds1 = new DataSet();
command = new SqlCommand(theQ, con);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue(1, "1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(2, betweenSplit[0].Replace(" BETWEEN ", ""));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(3, betweenSplit[1]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(4, Session["UCat"].ToString());

da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(_ds1, dbName);
da.Dispose();
closeAllConnections();
command.Parameters.Clear();
```

The error occurs on the line:

> da.Fill(_ds1, "tripData");

What would I be doing incorrectly **because the same query above works just fine when running it in Server Management Studio**?

Comment: I would say using ApproxData > '09/30/2016' AND  ApproxData < '09/30/2017' would be the ideal fix. I have never been a fan of between simply because linq statements never convert properly.

Comment: You need to use ANSI standard date literals so it will work with any language. YYYY-MM-DD. Also, between is not likely going to get you what you want here because it will skip any values on 2017-09-30 if the timestamp is later than midnight. Here is a great article on the evils of between. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @Programmer Still the same error even doing it that way :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to avoid implicit conversion of date to/from string.

In your case it could be (for example):

```
CONVERT (datetime, '09/30/2016',101)
```

Comment: Just to understand: you are executing the query (modified with CONVERT) directly in SSMS and you obtain the same error? OK I saw the line in your question...

Comment: No I am executing it within my C# code. However, it does work in SSMS.

Comment: ApproxDate in the db is a datetime, isn't it? (I apologize if I ask apparently obvious things)

Comment: Yes, it is set to datetime.

Comment: Mine can be a silly suggestion, but what do you think to try in C# to substitute  your     command.Parameters.AddWithValue(3, betweenSplit[1]);         with   command.Parameters.AddWithValue(3,  Convert.ToDateTime( betweenSplit[1] ) );      (and also for first date parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Datetime parameter to SQL like that

```
var yourFromDate = DateTime.Now;
SqlParameter fromDate = new SqlParameter("@val2", SqlDbType.DateTime) {Value = yourFromDate}; 
command.Parameters.Add(fromDate);
```